# Is it necessary to use template parameters to refer to same class inside definition?

Tags: c++

Is this necessary:

```
 template <typename T>
 class A{
   T*point;
   A<T> someFunction(){} //instead of returning just "A", not "A<T>"
 }
```

Will `someFunction` implicitly return the `A` of the same type as the class being defined? Because outside the class, you can only refer to this type as `A<float>` or similar, so I'd assumed this was necessary inside the class as well. I discovered it compiles without the <> so this made wonder if it is a safe habit to omit the brackets.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's valid and safe C++ to omit the template parameters inside the class definition. In fact it's good practice, since you might add other template parameters with default values later on. You might forget to change `A<T>` to `A<T,SomeOtherParameter>` and get strange compile-time errors. Then just returning `A` will do it.

Answer (score 20):

You can say either `A<T>` or just `A`, and `A` means the same as `A<T>`. This is because of 14.6.1/1:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected-class-name [...] is equivalent to the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class template enclosed in `<>`.