# Recursive typedef function definition : std::function returning its own type

Tags: c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a state-machine. The state is represented by a function of type `callback_t` : `callback_t(int&)` which returns a function of same type.

I dont know how to implement it since recursive typed function seems not to be allowed.

Here what I tryied (as a toy) :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <functional>

typedef std::function< callback_t(int &) > callback_t ;
callback_t f1(int & i)
{
    i++;
    return f1;
}
callback_t f0(int & i)
{
    if(i==0) i++;
    return f1;
}
callback_t start(int & i)
{
    i=0;
    return f0;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    callback_t begin = start;
    int i=0;

    while(i<100)
        begin = begin(i);

    printf("hello world\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The error:

```
C:/work/tests/tests/main.cpp:4:41: error: 'callback_t' was not declared in this scope
typedef std::function< callback_t(int &) > callback_t ;
                                       ^
```

Is there a way to implement this kind of behaviour ?

Env : win7, codelite, mingw 4.8.1

Comment: You compiled your program with -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11, right?

Comment: g++  -c  "C:/work/tests/tests/main.cpp" -std=c++11 -g -O0 -Wall  -o ./Debug/main.o -I. -I.

Comment: Please provide a more descriptive title. As is, whoever finds this in their search results will not be able to judge if it is worth checking out because this title could describe anything.

Comment: @R. Martinho Fernandes : what do you think now ? Any suggestion ?

Comment: Cool, thanks for acting! Have a +1.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Since recursive type definition is not possible, you can declare a structure that carry the function and implicitly cast to it:

```
template< typename... T >
struct RecursiveHelper
{
    typedef std::function< RecursiveHelper(T...) > type;
    RecursiveHelper( type f ) : func(f) {}
    operator type () { return func; }
    type func;
};

typedef RecursiveHelper<int&>::type callback_t;
```

Example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c6d6c29f1718e121

Comment: I modified your sample to match my use case, works perfectly.

Comment: @norisknofun The best thing is that I do not understand how callback_t(int&) is converting to callback_t because it is different type! Some how it work but I wouldn't relay on it.

Comment: @Arpegius Probably because of the template constructor of `std::function` :)

Comment: @Drax Right i just forgot that `std::function` do a implicit conversion of return type :) it will not work with bare function pointer

Comment: I does not compile under vs2013. Any idea? If not, I will start another question ...

Comment: @Arpegius sorry to bother, but I don't get this line:
`typedef std::function< RecursiveHelper(T...) > type;`
What is RecursiveHelper(T...) in that case?
To my understanding, std::function should be templated with a function prototype, so something like RETURN_TYPE (ARGS)

Comment: @Ervadac It is a function definition. A function that return a copy of RecursiveHelper, and get any parameter from that are pass to this template.

Comment: @Arpegius Well, that was fast thanks. I don't see why RecursiveHelper can be used without <T> and cannot be used with it. This does not work: `typedef std::function< RecursiveHelper<T>(T...) > type;`

Comment: @Ervadac It is a C++11 code. You cannot compile it without variadic template support. BTW it should be `typedef std::function< RecursiveHelper<T...>(T...) > type;` .

Comment: @Arpegius Yes I know and I know it compiles and works, I just talk about using RecursiveHelper as a return type without its template parameter. Ok got it thanks.

Comment: @Ervadac Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938480/is-it-necessary-to-use-template-parameters-to-refer-to-same-class-inside-definit

Comment: Question is tagged as C++11, so consider `using` instead of `typedef`.

Answer (score 6):

A little library for substituting one type for another:

```
template<class T>struct tag{using type=T;};

template<class X, class A, class B> struct subst:tag<X>{};
template<class X, class A, class B>
using subst_t=typename subst<X,A,B>::type;

template<class A, class B> struct subst<A,A,B>:tag<B>{};
template<class X, class A, class B>
struct subst<X&,A,B>:tag<subst_t<X,A,B>&>{};
template<class X, class A, class B>
struct subst<X&&,A,B>:tag<subst_t<X,A,B>&&>{};
template<class X, class A, class B>
struct subst<X const,A,B>:tag<subst_t<X,A,B>const>{};
template<class X, class A, class B>
struct subst<X volatile,A,B>:tag<subst_t<X,A,B>volatile>{};
template<class X, class A, class B>
struct subst<X const volatile,A,B>:tag<subst_t<X,A,B>const volatile>{};
template<template<class...>class Z,class...Xs, class A, class B>
struct subst<Z<Xs...>,A,B>:tag<Z<subst_t<Xs,A,B>...>>{};
template<template<class,size_t>class Z,class X,size_t n, class A, class B>
struct subst<Z<X,n>,A,B>:tag<Z<subst_t<X,A,B>,n>>{};
template<class R,class...Xs, class A, class B>
struct subst<R(Xs...),A,B>:tag<subst_t<R,A,B>(subst_t<Xs,A,B>...)>{};
```

now we use it:

```
struct own_type {};

template<class Sig>
struct recursive_func{
  using func=std::function< subst_t<Sig, own_type, recursive_func> >;
  template<class...Ts>
  std::result_of_t<func const&(Ts...)>
  operator()(Ts&&...ts)const{
    return f(std::forward<Ts>(ts)...);
  }
  operator func const&()const&{return f;}
  operator func&()&{return f;}
  operator func()&&{return std::move(f);}
  template<class F,
    class=std::enable_if_t<
      !std::is_same<recursive_func,std::decay_t<F>>::value
      && std::is_convertible<F,func>::value
    >
  >
  recursive_func(F&&fin):f(fin){}

  func* operator->(){return f;}
  func const* operator->()const{return f;}
private:
  func f;
};
```

which gives you a lovely syntax:

```
recursive_func< std::vector<own_type>() > f;
```

is a function that returns a vector of its own type.

This uses a smattering of C++14 `_t` aliases.  `std::blah_t<?>` can be replaced with `typename std::blah<?>::type` if your compiler is strictly C++11.  There may be other typos.

A weakness is that templates that expect their types to satisfy some property in the immediate context may fail when fed `own_type`.  This can be fixed with a delayed template applicator that `subst` understands, but in casual use is unlikely to be a problem.

[live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b9e73c8fa0b2f2a7)

Comment: I'm absolutely sure this answer can help me with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37219718/how-do-you-make-a-recursive-template-typedef but I'm unsure how to apply it to a type, rather than to a function.

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef std::function< callback_t(int &) > callback_t ;
                       **********
```

You try to define a new type with the definition itself. This is not possible! You can't use callback_t before it is defined.