# C++ std::function that returns a vector of it's own type (recursive types again)

Tags: c++, c++11, recursion, types, thunk

Ideally, I'd like to declare the following type:

```
using action_t = std::function< std::vector< action_t >(void) >
```

This is a thunk which returns a vector of followup thunks.  I was able to get this far using information from [Recursive typedef function definition : std::function returning its own type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23737449/recursive-typedef-function-definition-stdfunction-returning-its-own-type) :

```
struct RecursiveHelper                                                                                                                                     
{                                                                                                                                                          
  typedef std::vector<RecursiveHelper> rtype;                                                                                                              
  typedef std::function< rtype (void) > ftype;                                                                                                             
  RecursiveHelper( ftype f ) : func(f) {}                                                                                                                  
  rtype operator()() const { return func(); }                                                                                                              
  operator ftype () { return func; }                                                                                                                       
  ftype func;                                                                                                                                              
};                                                                                                                                                         

using action_t = RecursiveHelper;                                                                                                                          
using actions_t = std::vector<RecursiveHelper>;
```

However, to push these things onto a stack, for instance, I have to do things like this:

```
std::stack<action_t> stack;                                                                                                                            

stack.push(RecursiveHelper([&visitor, &node](void){                                                                                                    
    return visitor.visitNode(node);                                                                                                                    
    }));
```

Ideally I'd like to avoid any mention of `RecursiveHelper` in code which uses this stuff, if they want a stack of action_t, they should be able to push conforming lambdas straight onto it.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write a constructor that accepts any function object that is convertible to `ftype` and isn't `RecursiveHelper`:

```
template<class F, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_convertible<F, ftype>::value &&
                          !std::is_same<RecursiveHelper, std::decay_t<F>>::value>>
RecursiveHelper( F&& f ) : func(std::forward<F>(f)) {}
```

For C++11, replace `something_t<...>` with `typename something<...>::type`.

Comment: Awesome, thanks!  I in fact just got rid of my other copy constructor.  Are there any other move operators or anything I should be implementing in RecursiveHelper to keep overhead low, or does that cover all the bases?

Comment: @experquisite The compiler-generated ones should be fine.

Comment: Most of that sfinae is useless, because **any** type is convertable to `ftype` in the immediate context (aka, `std::function` sucks).  I guess it future proofs your code?

Comment: @Yakk That's been fixed, IIRC. http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-defects.html#2132