# Recursive(?) function wrapper based on std::function<>

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to achieve code looking similar to that

```
using ProcessCallback = std::function<ProcessCallback (const std::vector<char>&)>

// ...

ProcessCallback callback;
// initialize callback somehow...

while (/* condition */)    {
    auto callback_successor = callback (data);
    if (callback_successor)   {
       callback = std::move (callback_successor);
    }
}
```

In general I want to have callable `callback` object (function pointer, whatever) that will process some data and has possibly of replacing itself for successive calls.

The error is obvious - quasi-recursive declaration in first line is invalid, because I try to declare `std::function<>`-based type using undeclared `ProcessCallback`.

How can I fix aforementioned code or how can I achieve desired functionality with other construction? Abstract functional class for processing it's not the solution - I don't want to write new class inheriting from the abstract class for each processing function.

I want to stick to pure C++ (no Boos etc.), but I'm not limited to specific C++ version.

**Edit**

Actually I managed to workaround the problem, but I'm curious whether it;s possible to make initial solution working.

Comment: `void*` would definitely be an option, but then you might have to turn away from std::function and start working with function pointers.

Comment: @SebastianHoffmann sure, but it's a "ugly" C hack I want to avoid - that's one of reasons of using C++ ;)

Comment: What's the reason you don't just return a function pointer?

Comment: @JamesRoot because it will restrict functionality - I will not be able to e.g. return std::bind<> from processing functions.

Comment: Isn't `using` just syntactic sugar? If you can't write something without `using` then you won't be able to make magic happen with a recursive `using`.

Comment: Something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/q/23737449/2069064

Answer (score 0):

The easiest approach that springs to my mind is using a class that provides the functionality you want. As an example:

```
struct Callback{
    std::function<void(void)> func;
    Callback* next = nullptr;

    Callback* call(){
        func();
        return next;
    }
};
```

It is somewhat like a linked list, containing the function to call and a pointer to the next element. Of course it could also (conditionally) just return `this` and/or modify `func` to change its own behaviour without pointing to a different object. `call()` could also be `operator()()` here for even easier syntax.

Use is quite simple, by defining a pointer to `Callback` and then call

```
ptr = ptr->call();
```

[Try it online](http://ideone.com/bKoBX4)