# Function returning a pointer to the same function

Tags: c++

In this code a function returns a pointer to itself

```
typedef void (*voidfunc)();

voidfunc f(int) {
    return (voidfunc) f;
}
```

and generates the assembly was expecting, but uses a cast to a different function type to do so. How can this be done without casting in C++?

In other words what can be placed instead of `???` in the following snippet?

```
??? f(int) {
    return f;
}
```

I tried first with

```
auto f(int) {
    return f;
}
```

but it doesn't work, then I tried with templates but it didn't work either.

Comment: You can't do that in C++ (or in any language with a somewhat reasonable type system).

Comment: Related/dupe: [Function Returning Itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536504/function-returning-itself) and [Can a function return a pointer to its own type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49575096/can-a-function-return-a-pointer-to-its-own-type)

Comment: I actually searched first, but those questions and answers didn't show up :-/

Comment: @molbdnilo [Not really](https://go.dev/play/p/Zvl_9NZqMir).

Comment: @PasserBy Note "somewhat reasonable".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible since the type of the function would need to be contain an infinite recursion.

The version with the cast is also not useful. Any actual use of the return value would need to cast back to the actual function type.

Without additional information about the use case it is difficult to make a recommendation to solve this.

Comment: I used a `void(*)()` because a `void *` cannot be used portably with an address of a function (only with addresse of objects, and functions are not objects in C++). This problem surfaced when I was thinking about returning a continuation. In my code I'm just returning a 64-bit integer but wondered if there was a way to do it "cleanly" (I'm not a purist at all... it was just out of curiosity).