# Replacing std::function from within itself (by move-assignment to *this?)

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, std-function, this-pointer

Is it possible to replace one `std::function` from within itself with another `std::function`?

The following code does not compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

int main()
{
    std::function<void()> func = []()
    {
        std::cout << "a\n";
        *this = std::move([]() { std::cout << "b\n"; });
    };
    func();
    func();
    func();
}
```

Can it be modified to compile?
The error message right now is: *'this' was not captured for this lambda function* - which I completely understand. I don't know, however, how I could capture `func`'s `this`-pointer. I guess, it is not even a `std::function` inside the lambda, yet?! How can this be done?

*Background:* What I want to achieve is the following: In the first invocation of a given `std::function`, i would like do some initialization work and then replace the original function with an optimized one. I want to achieve this transparently for the user of my function.

The expected output of the example above is:

> a
>   b
>   b

Comment: A lambda is a prvalue, so you cannot assign to it. Have you considered creating a callable wrapper type?

Comment: Yes, that would probably work. However, I'd like to add as little additional code as possible and I am curious, if it can be done with `std::function` only.

Comment: Can the lambda be made aware of the `std::function` which will finally hold it, so the `std::function`'s this-pointer would be available inside the lambda?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `this` inside a lambda to refer to the lambda. `this` will only refer to the enclosing class, which in your case there is none so you cannot use `this`. What you can do however is capture `func` and reassign that:

```
std::function<void()> func = [&func]()
{
    std::cout << "a\n";
    func = []() { std::cout << "b\n"; }; // note the missing move, a lambda
                                         // is already an rvalue
};
```

Note however that if you let `func` outlive its scope (say by returning it from a function by value) without calling it first (effectively reassigning the stored function object) then you'll get a dangling reference.

> I guess, it is not even a `std::function` inside the lambda, yet?!

It actually is. A name comes into scope right after its declarator, so right before the `=`, `func` of type `std::function<void()>` is introduced. So at the point where you introduce the lambda, you can already capture `func`.

Comment: In the end I used an approach similar to this, which is why I chose this as the accepted answer. It is simple and clear but not as generic as the other answer proposed by Yakk.

Answer (score 3):

This technically solves your problem:

```
std::function<void()> func = [&func]{
  std::cout << "a\n";
  func = []{ std::cout << "b\n"; };
};
```

But it is not a good plan.  The lifetime and behaviour of the std function is tied to a local stack variable.  Copies fail to do what you probably want in almost any sense -- they continue to print `"a\b"` unless they segfault because the original `func` fell out of scope.

---

To fix this we have to deploy some big guns; to start with, the Queen of functional programming, Ms. Y Combinator:

```
std::function<void()> func = y_combinate( [](auto&& self){
  std::cout << "a\n";
  self = []{ std::cout << "b\"; };
} );
```

The Y Combinator takes a function of the signature `F = (F,Args...)->R`, then returns a function of the signature `(Args...)->R`.  It is how stateless languages manage recursion when you cannot name yourself before you are given a name.

Writing a Y Combinator is easier than you would fear in C++:

```
template<class F>
struct y_combinator_t {
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)
  -> typename std::result_of< F&( F&, Args&&... ) >::type
  {
    return f( f, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};
template<class F>
y_combinator_t<typename std::decay<F>::type> y_combinate( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

sadly this doesn't work as the type of `self` passed to a lambda is actually the type of the original lambda.  And the b-printing lambda is an unrelated type.  So when you try to `self = []{ std::cout << "b\n"; }` you get an error embedded in some relatively deep template spam errors.

Sad; but just a temporary setback.

What we need is a type very difficult to name -- a `F = std::function<void(F)>` -- a `std::function` that takes as its one argument an instance of an object of the same type.

There is usually no way to do this, but with a bit of template tomfoolery... [Here, I did it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29533782/1774667) before.

Then your code reads:

```
std::function<void()> func = y_combinate( recursive_func< void(own_type&) >([](auto&& self){
  std::cout << "a\n";
  self = [](auto&&){ std::cout << "b\n"; };
}) );
```

and a call to a given copy of `func` first prints `"a\n"`, then each later call prints `"b\n"`.  Copies of b-printers also print b, but copies of a-printers will print a the first time before transitioning.

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/96824c7699546b41).

`self` in this code is a `recursive_func< void(own_type&) >`, so you can do the same thing within the b-printer as you did in the a-printer.