# How can a lambda capture itself for an asynchronous call?

Tags: c++, asynchronous, recursion, lambda

I have to make an asynchronous call inside a lambda, and once the asynchronous call is terminated I have to call the lambda itself.

I try to explain my problem with code:

```cpp
typedef function<void(int id)> Callback;
```

```cpp
AsyncWork1(Callback call, int id, string)
{
    //...
    call(id);
}

AsyncWork2(Callback call, int id, double, string)
{
    //...
    call(id);
}
```

```cpp
void AsyncWorks(Callback final_callback, int id)
{
    Callback lambda = [&lambda, final_callback, id](int next_work) -> void
        {
            if(next_work == 1)
            {
                //...
                AsyncWork1(lambda, 2, "bla bla");
            }
            else if(next_work == 2)
            {
                //...
                //the lambda variable no longer exists
                AsyncWork2(lambda, 3, 0.0, "bla bla");
            }
            else if(next_work == 3)
            {
                //...
                final_callback(id);
            }
        };

    lambda(1);
}
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    AsyncWorks(...);

    AsyncWorks(...);

    AsyncWorks(...);

    AsyncWorks(...);

    return 0;
}
```

The problem is that when the code exits from "AsyncWorks(...)" function, the local variable "lambda" no longer exists.

I've read several threads that talk about lambda recursive, but I haven't found any solution.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You could probably do [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924996/lambda-with-dynamic-storage-duration) and have it delete itself at the end.

Comment: Beware that this design has flaws. There is no way to know that all the async tasks have finished by the time you `return 0;` from `main`. It's possible to implement this, but you might as well just use `std::async` and rely on the `std::future` it provides.

Comment: I know, this is a simple example, in the real application (based on FreeRTOS) this does not occur.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic problem is that C++ doesn't expose the `this` pointer of a lambda to itself.

As it happens, there are many languages where during something's definition, you cannot refer to itself.  This is fixed in functional languages using a technique called the "Y Combinator".

A simple y combinator in C++ looks like:

```
template<class F>
struct y_combinator_t {
  F f;
  template<class...Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&...args)
  -> std::result_of_t< F&( y_combinator_t<F>&, Args&&... ) >
  {
    return f( *this, std::forward<Args>(args)... );
  }
};
template<class F>
y_combinator_t<std::decay_t<F>> y_combinate( F&& f ) {
  return {std::forward<F>(f)};
}
```

I'm of two minds if we should `f( *this` or `f( f`, I sometimes do either.

Use:

```
void AsyncWorks(Callback final_callback, int id)
{
  Callback lambda = y_combinate(
    [final_callback, id]
    (auto& self, int next_work)
    -> void
    {
      if(next_work == 1) {
        //...
        AsyncWork1(self, 2, "bla bla");
      } else if(next_work == 2) {
        //...
        //the lambda variable no longer exists
        AsyncWork2(self, 3, 0.0, "bla bla");
      } else if(next_work == 3) {
        //...
        final_callback(id);
      }
    }
  );
  lambda(1);
}
```

basically, I added an implicit `self` parameter to the lambda function body.  Caller of the `operator()` don't see this parameter.

Y combinator based off [this post by myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50571486/1774667) with modifications.

Comment: `y_combinate` -> `y_combine`?

Comment: What does it mean "F&"?

Comment: @parmi F is a type -- F& is a reference to that type.  `F&( y_combinator_t<F>&, Args&&... )` is a signature of a function returning `F&` and taking `y_combinator_t<F>&, Args&&...`.  It is passed to `result_of_t`, which pretends the return type is the type of object you are passing the arguments to, and returns the type actually returned.  So we get "if you call an `F&` with `y_combinator_t<F>&, Args&&...`, whatever type that returns" is the return type of `y_combinator_t<F>::operator()(Args&&...)`.

Comment: @parmi all of which are technical details; the point is you write your lambda with `auto&self` as the first argument, and then pass it to `y_combinate`, and now you have access to a reference to yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Lambda can capture itself implicitly. To demo how? see below code it calculate factorial value.

```
#include <iostream>

int (* factorial)( const int) = []( const int number)
{
    if( number > 1)
    {
        return number* factorial( number - 1);
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
};

int main(int , char *[])
{
    int fact = factorial( 7);
    std::cout<< "7! = "<< fact<< std::endl;
}
```

```
Output 7! = 5040
```

If any variable is used inside lambda then lambda captures it implicitly, if it is not captured explicitly. Due to this inside lambda, name `factorial` referring itself, is available.
But if in place of
`int (* factorial)( const int) = []( const int number){//implementation };`
 if `auto` is used like as follows,
`auto factorial = []( const int number){ //implementation };`
then g++ compiler gives following error,
`error: use of ‘factorial’ before deduction of ‘auto’
         return number* factorial( number - 1);`
It is because type of `factorial` is not deduced, auto does not deduce for same control block. Name `factorial` will be available only below the declaration in case of `auto`.

Comment: So in conclusion, this works only if the lambda does not capture anything.

Comment: If lambda capture anything then it is not convertible to function pointer, because it becomes a class of unique name know only to compiler and then `auto` have to use and then what will happen is explained above. But it is not the purpose of lambda, like purpose of `std::map` is to provide key/value pair not random access, similarly purpose of lambda is to make quick anonymous callback functions with capture capability.

Comment: Your `factorial` is global too :-/

Answer (score 0):

@Yakk
To understand your answer I had to spend some time studying many c++ features, value category, rvalue, lvalue, move constructor, move assignment operator, variadic templates, variadic templates with implicit conversions, result_of_t<>, decay_t<>, forward<>.

But I don't have a thing yet, why did you put the '&' symbol here?

```
... std::result_of_t <F&(y_combinator_t<...
```

I also rewrote your solution to make it more specific for my case and easier to read and understand for me too (and for all those who are beginners with C++),

```
class y_combinator_t
{
public:
    function<void(y_combinator_t*, int, double, string)> callback;

    void operator()(int a, double b, string s)
    {
        this->callback(this, a, b, s);
    }
};

y_combinator_t combinator = {
    [id_work = 1]
    (y_combinator_t* _this, int a, double b, string s) mutable -> void
    {
        if(id_work == 1)
        {
            //...
            AsyncWork1(*_this, 2, 3.0, "bla bla");
            id_work = 2;
        }
        else if(id_work == 2)
        {
            //...
            AsyncWork2(*_this, 3, 0.0, "bla bla");
            id_work = 3;
        }
        else if(id_work == 3)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
};

//Start works
combinator(0, 0, "");
```