# In template class member function body outside class definition, when are template parameters required?

Tags: c++, c++98

This code compiles (Visual Studio 2013).  Note that I pass in `Set`, not `Set<T>`, as a parameter to operator=, in the function body which is outside the class definition.  But I can't return `Set` or have it be a member of `Set`; it must return `Set<T>` and be a member of `Set<T>`.

Where is it legitimate to leave out the template parameters?  [Inside the class definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16938480/is-it-necessary-to-use-template-parameters-to-refer-to-same-class-inside-definit), and where else?

Is this a change in the standard?  I'm trying to maintain compatibility with all existing versions, including 98.

```
template <typename T>
class Set 
{
public:
    Set() {}         

    const Set& operator=(const Set& rhs); 
    //Shouldn't this have to be 
    //const Set<T>& operator= (const Set<T>& rhs); ?

};

template <typename T>
const Set<T>& Set<T>::operator= (const Set& rhs) //<-- HERE
{
    Set temp;                                    //<-- AND HERE
    /* ... */
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    Set<int> S, T;
    T = S;
}
```

Comment: AFAIK only classes do this since they have an injected-class-name

Comment: and here: `template <typename T> auto Set<T>::operator=(const Set&) -> const Set&`

Comment: `void main` is invalid and would have prevented many (most) readers from trying out your code. I fixed that. Please don't post code with `void main` unless the question is specifically about that, because it misleads newbie readers and makes it impossible to just copy and paste your code to try it, unless one happens to be using one of the few compilers that accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name is made available in the class scope. And in a separate member definition, once you've passed the C++03 return type specification and the function name, you're in class scope. Thus, this is OK in C++03:

```
template< class T >
Set<T> const& Set<T>::operator=( Set const& rhs )
```

And this is OK in C++11:

```
template< class T >
auto Set<T>::operator=( Set const& rhs) -> Set const&
```

---

This doesn't really have anything to do with templates, but it has to do with accessing a name that's available in class scope.

For example, in C++03 you'd have to write

```
struct S
{
    struct Inner {};
    Inner foo();
};

S::Inner S::foo() { return Inner(); }
```

while with C++11 and later you can write

```
struct S
{
    struct Inner {};
    auto foo() -> Inner;
};

auto S::foo() -> Inner { return {}; }
```

which is one good reason, among many others, to adopt the trailing return type syntax as a single syntax convention.

---

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36653459/in-template-class-member-function-body-outside-class-definition-when-are-templa/36655831#comment60904860_36653459) is not OK in either C or C++, regardless of which year's standard:

```
void main() //! NOT VALID.
```

Comment: Do you know if what you have here is also valid in C++98?

Comment: The C++03 code is valid with C++98 compiler. The only new feature introduced in C++03 was value initialization. C++03 was just a *technical corrigendum* of C++98, called TC1 at the time (it was the first and only).